# Http client that is able to accept cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient

I try to access ba.com (actual url: "https://www.britishairways.com/travel/loginr/public/en_us?eId=109001)  by doing a POST with required parameters, it replies with a 3XX redirection that points to an url https://www.britishairways.com/cookie.html with `Set-Cookie` header. I try to do a GET using request header `Cookie` with `key=value;key=value ...`, at this point, it returns a 2XX saying cookie is not enabled.

For the gmail.com, it directly returns a 2XX response with `Set-Cookie` header when I do a POST with required parameters, and declares that cookie is not enabled.

My questions are:

1. Typically what would be the HTTP(S) sequences between client and server for the verification that cookie is enabled?
2. My general purpose is to access my account through program, log in, and check some information about my account. britshairways.com/gmail.com could be a good start. (This is kind like a simulated web browser)

If any one knows sample codes that could accomplish the task, I'd like to learn. Thanks.

Non-working sample codes below with detailed parameters to call britishairways.com/gmail.com

```
public static void PostToUrlWithCookies(string uri, NameValueCollection nvc, CookieCollection cookies, string cookieHeader = "")
{
    // this is what we are sending
    string post_data = "";
    if (nvc != null)
    {
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            string formitem = string.Format("{0}={1}", key, nvc[key]);
            if (post_data == "")
            {
                post_data += formitem;
            }
            else
            {
                post_data += "&" + formitem;

            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("post_data={0}", post_data);


    // create a request
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
    WebRequest.Create(uri);

    // to accept cookies (and skip 100 response)
    //var cookies = new CookieContainer(); 
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    string newCookieHeader = "";
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    if (cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        CookieCollection oCookies = cookies;

        for (int j = 0; j < oCookies.Count; j++)
        {
            Cookie oCookie = oCookies[j];
            Cookie oC = new Cookie();

            // Convert between the System.Net.Cookie to a System.Web.HttpCookie...
            oC.Domain = request.RequestUri.Host;
            oC.Expires = oCookie.Expires;
            oC.Name = oCookie.Name;
            oC.Path = oCookie.Path;
            oC.Secure = oCookie.Secure;
            oC.Value = oCookie.Value;

            if (newCookieHeader != "")
            {
                newCookieHeader += ";";
            }
            newCookieHeader += oC.Name + "=" + oC.Value;

            //request.CookieContainer.Add( oC );
        }

    }


    //      Console.WriteLine("request has {0} cookies inside", request.CookieContainer.Count);

    if (cookieHeader != "")
    {
        request.Headers["Cookie"] = newCookieHeader;
        Console.WriteLine("request Set-Cookie: {0}", newCookieHeader);
    }


    // add a fake cookie to request
    //Cookie aCookie = new Cookie("lastVisited", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    //aCookie.Domain = "ba.com";
    //request.CookieContainer.Add(aCookie);

    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    if (cookies.Count == 0)
    {
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;   // ba.com testing cookies using a 3XX Redirect
        request.Method = "POST";
    }
    else
    {
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Method = "GET";
    }
    //    
    // turn our request string into a byte stream
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

    // this is important - make sure you specify type this way
    if (request.Method == "POST")
    {
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        //      
        //      // now send it
        if (post_data != "")
        {
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        }
        requestStream.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2";
    }

    //       
    // grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
    {
        //               Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
        //              Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
        cookies.Add(cook);
    }

    cookieHeader = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
    Console.WriteLine("responce-> Set-Cookie: {0}", cookieHeader);


    for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine("\nHeader Name:{0}, Value :{1}", response.Headers.Keys[i], response.Headers[i]);


    if ((int)response.StatusCode >= 300 && (int)response.StatusCode < 400)
    {
        string cookieUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
        Console.WriteLine("about to verify cookie via url {0}", cookieUrl);




        // verify the cookie capability
        PostToUrlWithCookies(cookieUrl, null /*nvc*/, cookies, cookieHeader);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        Console.WriteLine((int)response.StatusCode);

    }


}
```

call for ba.com (format: uri, key, value pairs):

```
func "https://www.britishairways.com/travel/loginr/public/en_us?eId=109001","loginText", "Login+ID", "Directional_Login", "%2Ftravel%2Fechome%2Fexecclub%2Fen_us%3FmembershipNumber%3D36436959%26DM1%255FmktgCat%3DEmail%26DM1%255FMktgSubCat%3D2%26DM1%255Fcampaign%3DBBBB5YT0BPKCBBBB5YT0BQBG%26DM1%255FChksm%3D117285700%26DM1_SRC%3D%26utm_source%3DeD%26utm_medium%3DEmail%26utm_campaign%3DEmail%26utm_term%3DBBBB5YT0BQBG%26utm_content%3DBBBB5YT0BPKC", "membershipNumber", "XXXXXX", "password", "XXXXXX", "passwordtext", "XXXXXXX"
```

call for gmail.com

```
"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth", "continue", "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F", "dsh", "7157339180374789215", "hl", "en", "GALX", "f9V9sU8AY6c", "pstMsg", "1", "dnConn", "", "timeStmp", "", "secTok", "", "Email", "XXXXXXX@gmail.com", "Passwd", "XXXXXXX", "signIn", "Sign+in", "rmShown", "1"
```

Comment: Have you tried the `WebClient`? Not sure if it has built in cookie support, but I think so

Comment: What class/library do you use to access to `https://www.ba.com`. How does your code look like?

Comment: For the record, this is against the website's terms of service: "In particular, You agree that, You must not ... 
    use ‘screen scraping’, any automated algorithm, device, method, system, software or manual process to access, use, search, copy, monitor or extract Material (in whole or in part) from or through using this website unless We have given Our express written agreement;" https://www.britishairways.com/travel/termcn/public/en_us

Comment: I also note that https://www.ba.com has security issues, because the certificate doesn't match domain (http://ba.com redirects to https://www.britishairways.com/ but http://www.ba.com does the wrong thing, and attempts to serve up the same content.), certificate errors could cause problems with WebClient or WebRequest

Comment: I actually used "https://www.britishairways.com", see the parameter list in the post. Sorry for the confusion, it's not ba.com, I put it there just for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Adding cookie support to WebRequest is a few lines of code.

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

// perform normal request;
var webResponse; // be sure this gets assigned

cookies.Add(webResponse.Cookies);

// create another request
var webRequest; // be sure this gets assigned

webRequest.CookiesContainer = cookies;

// perform next request. This time with cookies.
```

Comment: This is correct, but be wary--I used it years ago and I think I ran into some obscure (but crippling) bugs. They might have fixed it by now, but buyer beware :)

Comment: I am currently unsure how it handles cookies being removed by the server. Sure, beware, test it for your use. But I use this in an app of mine, and it appears to work in my trivial cases.

Comment: Oh there's no doubt it works for trivial cases--I was using this to scrape several thousand unique websites when I encountered it ;). But it should be more than fine in most cases (thus the +1)

Comment: @Stargazer712 I figured you'd meant that, but didn't want to scare away the new user on his first question.

Comment: Please take a look at my implementation below, which is not working

Comment: @McKay In my sample codes (mostly for functionality only, excuse me for the style and formatting), I do try to set the cookie through both http header (and CookieContainer), in the case of gmail.com, the first reply directly tells me the cookie is not enabled. In the case of ba.com, I get a redirect to verify cookie, however the following step fails although I try to set the cookie. I'm sure something is wrong, but do not know what it is.

Comment: The new "code" you added doesn't show anything about cookies?

Comment: I comment it out, see the line //request.CookieContainer.Add( oC ); 
Uncommenting it does not do anything different.

Note that I use the request header "Cookie" in my codes, I tried to use CookieContainer in my first try which failed.